# Hide Files/Attachments in Opportunities for specific Profile

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

We have a profile that does not need to see notes/attachments/files inside of opportunities. How can I create an apex before insert trigger to look at the current user's profile and hide the attachments?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without code actually. Just create new layout for Opportunity, remove related lists from it and assign it to your specific profile.

You can find it in Page Layout Assignment in Page Layouts section.

Comment: This was also my first instinct, but it appeared as an inelegant solution as presumably access to those files would remain, just from a different place, no?